# Kotlin. Переход с ативити в активити которий отвечает за фрагменти

Tags: android, kotlin

Добрий день.
Проблема вот в чем.
У меня есть активити(LoginPage) и активити(MainActivity) которая отвечает за фрагмети.
И я хочу просто перейти с LoginPage в MainActivity через button.
Но в результате приложения крашитса.
Если интерсно какой код, то вот:

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.hospital

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var toolbar : Toolbar
private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
private lateinit var navigationView: NavigationView
private lateinit var navController: NavController
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
private lateinit var button: Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.myToolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer)
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)

    navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.id_home_fragment,R.id.id_contact_fragment, R.id.id_prav_fragment, R.id.id_proekt_fragment),drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController,drawerLayout)
    navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

}

**LoginPage**

```
package com.example.hospital

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class LoginPage : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page)

        val ButtonOpen: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)
        ButtonOpen.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hospital">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Hospital">
    
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginPage"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Logcat**

```
2022-04-22 09:48:59.344 3679-3679/com.example.hospital E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hospital, PID: 3679
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hospital/com.example.hospital.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    at com.example.hospital.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.hospital.Fragments.SignIn: make sure class name exists
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass(FragmentFactory.java:97)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:611)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:483)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
    at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:71)
    at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1066)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:639)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:592)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:557)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:539)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:248)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2949)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:278)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:706) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.example.hospital.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
 Caused by: ja
2022-04-25 21:43:03.652 5273-5295/com.example.hospital V/FA: Checking service availability
2022-04-25 21:43:03.656 5273-5295/com.example.hospital V/FA: Service available
2022-04-25 21:43:03.663 5273-5295/com.example.hospital V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2022-04-25 21:43:04.004 5273-5295/com.example.hospital V/FA: Detected application was in foreground
2022-04-25 21:43:04.048 5273-5295/com.example.hospital V/FA: Session started, time: 4057266
2022-04-25 21:43:04.150 5273-5295/com.example.hospital V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2022-04-25 21:43:04.156 5273-5295/com.example.hospital I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2022-04-25 21:43:04.873 5273-5295/com.example.hospital V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2022-04-25 21:43:04.883 5273-5295/com.example.hospital V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2022-04-25 21:43:04.888 5273-5295/com.example.hospital V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
```

Синим подсвечиваеться ета строчка :
at com.example.hospital.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27)

Comment: здесь все ОК, значит ошибка в другом месте.  прикрепите полный код ошибки.

Comment: Код кинул, заранее СПАСИБО)

Comment: скиньте код ОШИБКИ, пожалуйста

Comment: Откройте logcat - там будут красные строчки в момент падения с выделениями синим строчек в вашем коде, которые вызывают падение. Вот их нам надо в первую очередь - так будет ясно что именно у вас сломалось

Comment: at com.example.hospital.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:27)
Тут есть виделение синим(MainActivity.kt:27)

Comment: Еще я думаю што проблема скорей всего в Манифесте, посколько я оттуда удалил 1 поле што отвечало за activity. Manifest добавил)

Comment: Насчет виделения синим, оно виделело етот код:
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

Comment: 1. Нужно весь лог ошибки приводить - там есть класс ошибки и сообщение ошибки. Это крайне важная информация, почти единственно важная. Часто достаточно только её чтобы понять проблему, даже в код не глядя. Добавьте полный лог (красное) в вопрос. 2. В манифесте должны быть все активити, которые вы хотите запускать. Это может быть причиной ошибки. 3. Однако, раз в ошибке указан setContentView то проблема может быть и в разметке. Но без п1 нельзя сказать точно. Покажите (и всегда показывайте в первую очередь) полный лог ошибки

Comment: Привет. Добавил Logcat с класом ошибки + в Manifest добавил activity LoginPage как указано ниже кодом. Зарание Спасибо)

Comment: Самое интересное обрезано в конце лога:) Но уже видно что проблема во фрагменте. Добавьте остаток лога и код фрагмента (`com.example.hospital.Fragments.SignIn`), весь уже опубликованный код судя по всему к проблеме не имеет отношения

Comment: Добавил Лог до конца. Мне фрагмент SignIn не нужен. Могу удалить. Заранее Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Не указал MainActivity в Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hospital">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Hospital">
    
<activity
            android:name=".LoginPage"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```